# WP8 app crashes with exceptions

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing wp8 app. My question is that, The app is getting crashed when clicking on camera button and during camera scanning the image, when i move from app and then come back to the app. Its getting crashed. and i got following exception

An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: Place break points and trace at which part of code the exception is occuring. Post the code here, so that we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Actually on camera button click web service getting call but in the response of web service i got an error instead of what i should get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by Putting your code in UI Dispatcher BeginInvoke method.

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
             // your code    
            });
```

Comment: Thanks, now my app is not crashing but response of web service is not perfect. because the image, what i am scanning, is not matching with the server image.